# using both and & and or | at the same time in r?

Tags: r

I know how to use multiple `&`'s or multiple `|`'s at the same time. Is it possible to use both at the same time? Basically, I would like to combine the below codes, using the or command, into one line. Then I wouldn't have to merge `D` and `D2` to get my final output.

```
D <- subset(data, Quits1/Emp1 >= .5 & size == 1, )

D2 <- subset(data, Emp1 - Emp2 >= 100 & size == 1, )
```

Answer (score 4):

I have literally never used R in my life, so if I'm horribly wrong about this I'm sorry!

But I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work:

```
D <- subset(data, (Quits1/Emp1 >= .5 | Emp1 - Emp2 >= 100) & size == 1, )
```

However, as @shadow has pointed out, [use of `subset` is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset). So here's my attempt at using the proper method:

```
D <- data[ (data$Quits1 / data$Emp1 >= .5 | data$Emp1 - data$Emp2 >= 100) & data$size == 1,]
```

Comment: Congrats, you are officially an R programmer. Your certificate will arrive in the mail shortly.

Comment: This solves the question of the OP. If you had some experience in R, you would also point out that the use of `subset` is discouraged and standard subsetting functions like `[`.

Comment: FWIW, shadow is referring to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9860090/324364), although I wouldn't sweat it in this instance.

Comment: You were close; I added a comma.

Comment: @joran Damn, so close XD Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. The initial subsetting suggestion worked. The one with [] did not. All of my data came back NA when trying to use that code.